# How to calculate person months for postdoc proposal when planning to work full time on multiple work packages?

Tags: application, postdocs, working-time, research-proposal

I am currently in the process of preparing my proposal for a postdoc position. In specific parts of the proposal I need to refer to person months for each work package. I will be the project coordinator and the leader of all six packages, as this is a small, qualitative research project that requires only me and my mentor. I assumed that I will work full time = 12.00 for each work package, but the sum comes to 72 months! How should I complete this section?

Comment: If the six projects take equal effort, you can only at most dedicate 2 person-month to each of them, because 12/6 = 2. Notice that person-month is not a time line, it's how much time will elapse between start and finish; if you fill in 2, it just mean it needs about 60 days from a person, regardless how they are distributed along a year.

Comment: Working full-time on 6 projects would require you to put in 240 hours per week (40 hours x 6 projects). You are instead planning to spend one-sixth of your time working full-time of the time time on each project.

Comment: This is actually very helpful, thank you very much